# Can I stitch a label with my personal info in my shabbes clothes?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

I live far from my shul and there is no eruv in my city. Since I cannot carry my ID, can I stitch a label with my personal data in my clothes or this is considered carrying ?

Answer (score 13):

*Shmiras Shabbas Ke'Hilchasa* (18:44) writes that one may walk into a *Reshus HaRabbim* with an identification label that is sewn or stuck to one's garment.